# Why I cant pass an array of objects as a URL parameter from JavaScript to PHP using window.fetch?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, url-parameters

It is very strange that I couldn't find some posts related to this problem.

I have an array of objects and I want to pass it as parameter to PHP using `window.fetch` function:

```
var stringified_obj = JSON.stringify(trafficFilterHolder)
window.fetch('https://127.0.0.1/filters.php?filt=' + stringified_obj, { credentials: 'include' })
.then(function (data) {
    //
}).catch(function (err) {
   //
});
```

This is my PHP (simplified):

```
$trafficFilters = $_GET["filt"];
$JSON = json_encode($trafficFilters);
echo $JSON;
```

The response I get is:

[image]

Even if I try to return a simple message "Hello", i dont receive it back in JS:

```
 echo "Hello";
```

Comment: Are you okay with reqular AJAX or is fetch a must?

Comment: @WaisKamal I personally prefer AJAX but this entire project is using fetch so I dont want to switch styles you know . And it is a work task, not a personal one.

Comment: Because you can't just cram JSON into a URL parameter willy-nilly, you need to properly encode it. You also need to enable error reporting on the PHP side so that it actually tells you that something is wrong rather than returning a blank response.

Comment: @Sammitch how to properly encode it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+url+encode

Comment: @Sammitch if I use `encodeURIComponent ` how should I decode in PHP?

Comment: You don't. Given a properly-encoded URL PHP will decode it when it builds `$_GET`.

Comment: @Sammitch I am doing `$filter_holder = json_decode($trafficFilters);` in PHP and it works, because you must decode in PHP if you want to use that array. Now I am having a very strange problem tho, I can loop through it, I can access object, BUT I cant access a single field if I want to, such as `foreach ($filter_holder as $val) { $val['id']}` so it fails in this case, but if I return the entire object `$val` it does successfully. And there is `id` field for sure in each object.

Comment: @Sammitch i just realized that I should access PHP objects' fields like this `$value->id`

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something wrong + @Sammitch helped with encoding so here is the solution:

```
var stringified_obj = JSON.stringify(trafficFilterHolder)
window.fetch('https://127.0.0.1/filters.php?filt=' + encodeURIComponent(stringified_obj), { credentials: 'include' })
 .then(function (response) {
     return response.json(); //I added this callback to get the response
  }).then(function (data) {
    //
}).catch(function (err) {
   //
});
```